# How to access the current rows ID/primary_key that is being autoincremented on insert?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.5.0

So I want to create an ancestry column. It should be the ancestry column of the parent, plus the current rows id.

```
id | parent_id | ancestry
1 | nil | "/1/"
2 | 1 | "/1/2/"
3 | 2 | "/1/2/3/"
4 | nil | "/4/"
```

I've tried `currval('messages_id_seq')` which returns `currval of sequence "messages_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session`

I've tried `nextval('messages_id_seq') - 1` which works but seems unreliable (maybe subject to race conditions?)

I saw one example that used

```
INSERT INTO "messages" ("id" "body" ...)
VALUES (default $1 ...)
RETURNING "id" ["Message body" ...]
```

I am using an database abstraction framework (Ecto, like ORM but not), which generates the following SQL. This makes is messy to try and implement the above SQL.

```
INSERT INTO "messages" ("body" ... )
VALUES ($1 ...)
RETURNING "id" ["Message body" ...]
```

Is there any clean alternative? Ecto allows a `fragment` default (which is how I did currval/nextval).

Comment: Why do you think `nextval()` is unreliable? (And no, it is **not** subject to race conditions). It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Do you already **have** the `id` and `parent_id` columns? Do you want to create such a table? Do you want to insert into such a table? Are you aware that you can easily generate the `ancestry` column on the fly while querying the data?

Comment: IMO he wants a recursive query to construct a text path from the ids.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When I insert the row, it's without an ID. Postgres generates the ID, but I also want to use that ID to generate the ancestry column which is: ```parent_ancestry + ID + "/"``` Is there anyway to do this during the initial insert without doing update after the initial insert?

Comment: @joop I dont want to construct in when I query, I want it as a column, so I can query with regex: direct children of row 1 is ```/1/d+/``` all children is ```/1/(d+/)+```, etc.

Comment: You want the parent_id (*previous* sequence) while inserting? Short answer: impossible. (you *could* do this in a loop, `RETURNIG id` and let the frontend use that id as parent_id on the next insert. That would take care of *holes* as well)

Comment: @joop My issue is not the parent_id/ancestry, I look that up before the insert. My issue is appending the current rows ID to the ancestry during the insert. Given that someone is creating the 3rd row (we can't always assume the id will be 3 as postgres doesnt guarantee sequential ids wont have holes). I will know that 2's ancestry is ```/1/2/```, then when the 3rd item is inserted, postgres will autoincrement, assign the id 3, then I want to insert ```/1/2/3/``` in the "ancestry" column for that row at the same time. Perhaps that's not possible?

Comment: I am not familiar with Postgre, but this is the sort of task that a trigger or a calculated field can usually handle in most databases.

Comment: You could look up the path for the parent, too. and append the new id to it: `par.path || '/' || this.id::text